# Submit Button in Bootstrap 3 Modal Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, submit

I want the form to submit to the same page, so I left the form action black. I've tried using `<button type="submit">`, `<input type="button">` and `<input type="submit">`.  [Here is the live version](http://evanwknight.com/IH) for more context. When you click "Add Student," then click the "Save Student Info" button, it does nothing, but the close button works.

Here is the code for my modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new student</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputID" placeholder="Student ID Number">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLast" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirst" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Street Address">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="City">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputState" placeholder="State">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBalance" placeholder="Current Balance">
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTerm" placeholder="First Term Attended">
                    </div>
                </div> 

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <input type="submit" value="Save Student Information" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: It is working fine. Which browser you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your submit button is outside of the  tag. Just make the form wrap the whole modal window like this...

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
         <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputID" placeholder="Student ID Number">
                        </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLast" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirst" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Street Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="City">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputState" placeholder="State">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBalance" placeholder="Current Balance">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div 

class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTerm" placeholder="First Term Attended">
                    </div>
                </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <input type="submit" value="Save Student Information" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 9):

you can also link a button (or input) outside of a form by using the HTML5 attribute : form

exemple from w3schools website :

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't require your markup to be shuffled around! It's too bad the form-attribute uses the form id and not the form name, and apparently it isn't supported in IE and Edge, but honestly, who cares... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the atribute `data-dismiss = "modal"` in

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: Explain why this would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because the submit button is outside the form element.

Wrap the form element around .modal-body - that will ensure that all the form fields and input buttons are in the form to be submitted.

Also, apply some styling to the form with 0 padding and 0 margin as it may push the form making the modal look untidy.

Hope it helps, this is what I do anyway and it works fine for me.

Comment: "Wrap the form element around .modal-body - that will ensure that all the form fields and input buttons are in the form to be submitted." That is not true. The submit and cancel button are in the modal footer. When I wrap the form element around the modal-body nothing will happen on clicking the submit button...